# Error EPERM: Operation not permitted RENAME

Tags: visual-studio-code, rename, liveserver

I'm using LiveServer on vsCode, I usually study and ctrl c and ctrl v on folders and just rename them and study the new content. But every time I rename these copied folders, VScode gives me a problem.
"EPERM error: RENAME operation not allowed"
I'm using pure JavaScript, no frameWork, just .js and html file

I already opened VScode as an administrator, the problem persisted...
If I'm going to rename the copied folders directly by explorer, I can usually do...
I can only rename folders when I close VSCode or disable the LiveServer port